# Отправка запроса на nodejs express

Tags: node.js, http, express, request

Отправляю на сервер данные формата:

Метод: POST
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
alerts: [
    {test1: 21,
     test2: 22,
    }
  ],
}
```

Как такое правильно отправить, в Postman, например?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так, это пример в Postman:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думал - проблема в запросе. Оказалось - нет, на express приходит нормально (проверил req.body). Реальная проблема - те объекты, что в массиве при сохранении в mongo db - пусты. Если добавить кавычки вокруг объекта - сохраняет. Также, могу добавить поля через mongo express. https://prnt.sc/umjz3a     alerts - как строка, а вот поле name создано через mongo express. Не могу задать его, например, в postman, в базу ложится пустой объект.